# how to rename the global dojo, dijit & dojox global variables during build time (dojo 1.8.x)

Tags: dojo

We are planning to use dojo 1.8 alongside with a legacy version (1.2). We want the global variable dojo to point to 1.2 version of dojo and dojo18 to point to 1.8 version. I tried using the packages attribute of dojoConfig to get this to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<some_path>/dojo-release-1.2.0/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script>
  djConfig = {};
  var dojoConfig = {
      parseOnLoad: true,
      async: true,
      baseUrl: '<some_path>/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo',
      packages: [
                 {name: 'dojo18', location: '<some_path>/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo', 
                     packageMap: {
                         dojo: 'dojo18', 
                         dijit: 'dijit18', 
                         dojox: 'dojox18'
                     }
                 },
                 {name: 'dijit18', location: '<some_path>/dojo-release-1.8.3/dijit'},
                 {name: 'dojox18', location: '<some_path>/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox'},
                ],
      deps: ["dojo18", "dijit18", "dojox18"]
  };
</script>
<script src="/cuic/scripts/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

This however doesn't seem to work - now there re 2 global variables - dojo and dojo18 - both of which point to 1.8 version of Dojo.

Since relocation of packages of compiled version of Dojo is not working, I was wondering if there are any build properties exposed that change dojo to dojo18, dijit to dijit18, dojox to dojox18 by doing a custom build of dojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the custom build to create a global variable 'dojo18', 'dijit18' 'dojox18' - by modifying the dojo/_base/kernel code's scopeMap variable.

```
    var scopeMap =
                // a map from a name used in a legacy module to the (global variable name, object addressed by that name)
                // always map dojo, dijit, and dojox
                {
                    dojo:["dojo18", dojo],
                    dijit:["dijit18", dijit],
                    dojox:["dojox18", dojox]
                },
```

This configuration ensures that the global variables will be named as 'dojo18' instead of 'dojo'.
The scopeMap variable seems to be respected in the earlier versions of dojo, when provided via the dojoConfig variable. But it doesn't seem to work in 1.8.x versions. I wonder if this is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a TOTAL shot in the dark ...

the .8 invocation creates a dojo instance .. that's normal ... and it kills your old dojo.

Try cloning the dojo object which is created in line 1 to another variable, immediately following the instantiation. Then following the rest of the process, clone the 1.8 dojo instance also to another variable.

Finally clone the new variables back into dojo and dojo18 respectively ...

No promises, but it's a quick thing you can try before you get too deep in and I'm also interested to see if it works. If it does work you should also be able to use djConfig for the first instance and dojoConfig for the second ...

Sorry ... I'm on my mobile so I can't test it :) ...

Later .. a really scruffy test, but this worked ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >var dojette = dojo;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" >var dojo18 = dojo;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >var dojo = dojette;
  console.log(dojo.version);
  console.log(dojo18.version);
</script>
```

and if you dump dojo and dojo18 as complete objects you'll find they are complete with functions etc. I didn't go any further with separating out the module namespaces etc, so the rest of my code still blew up, but it's a start ... I hope it helped ...

Comment: Thanks for the response Radiotrib - but I wanted a more cleaner way to get this done.

Comment: I don't blame you :) ... I'm also in the process of transitioning quite a few thousand lines of dojo 1.4 into Dojo 1.8 but I decided to go at it the hard way :) ... freze the old code and rewrite the lot ... aaaagh!!!!